# Access Denied error when trying to connect to Firebird in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, firebird

I recently have it working that, within Visual Studio, I can see Firebird as a data provider.

The project I am working on I am trying to get the embedded version of Firebird working to use in my c# program

However, when I go to Tools/Connect to Database
Choose firebird Data source I enter the following

Data source:  Firebird Data Source (.net framework data provider for firebird)
Data Source:   is blank
Data Source Port:  3050
Dialect:  3
charSet:  NONE
Database:  path to my fdb file
Server Type:  Embedded
user:  username I setup
password:  password I setup
role:  is blank

when i click test connection, it immediately pops up that access is denied.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you connect to the same server and database using isql or the tool of your preference?

Comment: Yes.  the application still runs just fine using MS SQL CE as I am still developing in that until I can move to Firebird.

Comment: you're not answering my question, please, read carefully ;)

Comment: Sorry about that.  My bad.  Yes I can.  I used flamerobin to create the database and generate some test tables and views and it works no problem.  I also manually generated a connection string, created an fbconection and command via code and it works that way as well.

Comment: could you finally get it to work with @jachguate's and/or my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The Embedded edition of the database open the database file(s) in exclusive mode (DenyRead, DenyWrite), the server edition do the same thing.

That's *by design*, there's no way of coordination between two different database processes to allow to open that file and perform read/write operations successfully in a concurrent environment.  If you want to allow different processes access to the database, you must do it connecting to a server edition of the Firebird product.

**This is true also for your development environment**.  If you connect your IDE to the database using embedded, then execute your application using also embedded, the application will get an access denied error, because the file will be opened by the IDE.  As you may know, the IDE and your application are, in fact, different processes.

Other possible scenario is when you're working with this database from FlameRobin or any other tool (using the server edition or the embedded one) and then you try to open the connection from the IDE using the embedded edition.

Because of that, **using the embedded edition in the development environment is a bad idea**.

What I do is **always use a local server** there.  That way, I can connect my IDE database tools to the database (rarely, but sometimes I do that), any other tool, like isql, IBExpert, FlameRobin, I can maintain open connections from my project and run to test/debug without problems.

Then, if the application will use the embedded version in production, **I switch to that version during the test/Q&A phase, and of course, on production**.

I'm not using Firebird from Visual Studio or .NET, so I'm not sure what's the meaning of the `Server Type: Embedded` parameter, or how the driver chooses between server and embedded, but whatever it is, you have to change it only in your release versions, while using server in debug versions.

Now, **I must confess**, I lie at the beginning of this answer, in fact using classic server, there are several processes (one for each connected client) accessing the database.  I'm not sure how they share's access to that file between different process (maybe there are a reader/writer process, I don't know and, for now, I really don't care), that's another story and does not change what I say before.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply.  Sounds like i need to get the client/server setup for firebird and run with that.  Then on deployment, i can utilize the embedded version right?  Any tricks needed to make it work making this use the embedded version versus the client/server setup used during dev?

Comment: nothing special... just, you can't make connections from different processes. For example, running your application twice will not be possible.  Everything else, from your application point of view, is the same IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to connect using a FBConnection component, and the connection prompt looks like [this](http://www.firebirdsql.org/firebirdtutorial/fbconnection-component.html)

In that case what you call "Data Source" and tell us that is blank should point to localhost for an embedded database. Check the link I provided for more information.

If you are not using a FbConnection then please provide some more information about the connection component and connection string.

**EDIT**

Reading the information you add in your comments it seems you are trying to establish a connection to Firebird using ADO.NET (can not test it since I do not have Visual Studio installed on this machine), which is concordant with what I supposed earlier.

When you configure a connection to a Firebird database you are constructing a *connection string* which is used by your connection components to know how to connect to the database (please note that this applies also to several other databases when configuring the connection).

You can find more information about connection strings [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) and specifical to Firebird [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird).

As far as I know Firebird can be accessed from .NET in two ways:

- *Using ADO.NET*: In this case you need to set *Data Source* to localhost. I think this is your case.
- *Using ODBC through .NET*: In this case the connection looks very different. You can check it at the links I provided but I doubt that applies to your case.

So, in short version, please try to set "Data Source" to localhost.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I should give a little more information possibly.  I have a database in Windows SqlCE in my project currently but it does not do everything required so am attempting to make the move to Firebird.  In Windows SQL CE i had a dataset setup via dataset designer where I pulled in my tables, created relationships, etc.  I am wanting to do the same via Firebird and am trying to get Firebird setup as a datasource to allow me this same functionality. this is where my error is occuring trying to setup the connection.

Comment: Limited in characters.  Here is the path to where I am attempting to set this up:  Data/Add New Data Source/Database/Dataset/New Connection Choose Firebird Data Source.  It is similar to your screenshot then above where I enter the information as in that screen.  this is the screen that I get the access denied error.  does that help?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide some more information. Anyway, did you try to set "Data Source" to "localhost"?

Comment: You are right.  I did create a connection manually in code using fbconnection and passing a striing with the connection string and I am able to read/write to the database.   It is creating this using the wizard that seems to be the issue possibly.  When I clicked on the link in your first post and I drag the fbconnection into my form and attempt to edit the connection string the elipse aren't there to bring up the wizard.  Do you think the install is incorrect or broken? Is this wizard trying to right out a file and doesn't have access maybe? thanks again for the help.

Comment: oh i should have noted too that I did set the data source to localhost and i get the same error.

Comment: I doubt the install is broken but maybe it does not allow you to edit the connection string directly. Since you can access the database when creating the fbConnection at runtime it looks like you problem now is more in the line of what @jachguate suggested. Anyway, just in case, could you paste in a comment the connection string you create manually and the one created by the wizard?

Comment: Here is the manual menthod:  //ServerType=1;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Dialect=3;Database=FIREBIRDDB.FDB

Comment: I haven't been able to get one created through the wizard.  When I enter the information to have it generated one and then hit test connection that is when i get the error.

Comment: The manual method will work with "Database=FIREBIRDDB.FDB" if the app and the database file are in the same folder since the ADO.NET provider allows for relative paths. However, I doubt this applies for the wizard. Try to set the connection using the absolute path.