# Firebird embedded with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, firebird

I am trying to use firebird embedded with Visual Studio 2010, but I can't figure out how to create the database from visual studio, or how to connect to it, or anything, and I can't find any tutorials on this.

If anyone has any links to some good explicit tutorials please post them down, or maybe you can give me a few short instructions on how to start.

I have used MySQL and MsSQL, and connected with both of them, but embedded databases are very different as far as I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this:

- [Interbase and Firebird Developer's manual for Visual Studio Net. Part 1. Introduction to 
  ADO .Net.](http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/firebird_adonet/firebird_adonet.html)
- [Beginner’s Tutorial on Using the Firebird ADO.NET Client 2.5](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Using_Firebird_ADO_NET.aspx)
- [Setting up a portable Firebird Full with VS 2010](http://www.basarat.com/2010/05/setting-up-portable-firebird-full-with.html)

Comment: The last link is 404. Possible replacement: http://www.firebirdnews.org/setting-up-a-portable-firebird-full-with-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 1):

I just ran through setting up firebird in vs2010.  I documented what I did here: [Create firebird data source in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446580/create-firebird-data-source-in-visual-studio/5447545#5447545)

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the database from inside your IDE.

Use isql or any other tool to create the database, for example in isql you can enter the following command to create a new database:

```
c:\>isql
sql>create database 'c:\path\to\database.fdb' page_size 8192 user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey';
```

Also read my answer about [connecting to Firebird embedded from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505675/access-denied-error-when-trying-to-connect-to-firebird-in-visual-studio/5517124#5517124)